# How to set tag in YouTrack on commit in SVN or TeamCIty build?

Tags: svn, teamcity, youtrack

I have a TeamCity + YouTrack + SVN. I commit to svn TeamCity build it, and YouTrack see changes for issues from commit message.
Now i want to add `tag` to issue in YouTrack. I know that i can add command like `#ISSSE-ID add tag my-tag`. But this is not a solution.
This is possible to add tags automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-19028 is implemented, you'll be able to create a workflow rule that will take am issue after a VCS change is attached to it.

Comment: That issue was created 7 years ago. Looks like this feature not will be implemented in observable future.

Comment: It's old indeed, but will be implemented within 2-3 months.